# NSwag - Common Operation Responses OperationProcessor

Tags: swagger, nswag

I'm setting up a new API using Clean Architecture solution from here: https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture

If we focus on the return types for the API.

1 - 200 - This API specification for this is generated fine (based on return type of the Action in Controller)

e.g. for `get/TodoItems`

```
"/api/TodoItems": {
  "get": {
    "tags": [
      "TodoItems"
    ],
    "operationId": "TodoItems_GetTodoItemsWithPagination",
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "",
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/PaginatedListOfTodoItemBriefDto"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    ]
  },
```

Then we have a couple of exceptions being handled in `ApiExceptionFilterAttribute` in the folder `WebUI/Filters/`

```
_exceptionHandlers = new Dictionary<Type, Action<ExceptionContext>>
            {
                { typeof(ValidationException), HandleValidationException },
                { typeof(NotFoundException), HandleNotFoundException },
                { typeof(UnauthorizedAccessException), HandleUnauthorizedAccessException },
                { typeof(ForbiddenAccessException), HandleForbiddenAccessException },
            };
```

`typeof(ValidationException)` is for Http status code `400`

`typeof(NotFoundException)` is for Http status code `404`

`typeof(UnauthorizedAccessException)` is for Http status code `401`

`typeof(ForbiddenAccessException)` is for Http status code `403`

Now, to make these populate in the swagger.json file we will need to decorate every single controller action with the following.

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ValidationException), 400)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(UnauthorizedAccessException), 401)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(NotFoundException), 404)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ForbiddenAccessException), 403)]
```

To avoid this, I thought of using the `IOperationProcessor` interface from `NSwag`. but I am having trouble generating the Schema for the returned type.

```
public class CustomResponseTypesOperationProcessor : IOperationProcessor
{
    public bool Process(OperationProcessorContext context)
    {
        var schema = context.SchemaGenerator.Generate(typeof(ValidationException));
        context.OperationDescription.Operation.Responses.Add("400", new OpenApiResponse { Description = "An error occurs or a business rule fails.", Schema = schema });

        return true;
    }
}
```

In `ConfigureServices`

```
    services.AddOpenApiDocument(configure =>
    {
        ...
        configure.OperationProcessors.Add(new CustomResponseTypesOperationProcessor());
    });
```

But when I build the project (it should generated the swagger.json and TS API client on build, I get the following error)

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Could not resolve the path '#/paths//api/TodoItems/get/responses/400/content/application/json/schema/definitions/Exception'.
1>   at NJsonSchema.JsonReferenceResolver.ResolveDocumentReference(Object rootObject, String jsonPath, Type targetType, IContractResolver contractResolver)
1>   at NJsonSchema.JsonReferenceResolver.ResolveReferenceAsync(Object rootObject, String jsonPath, Type targetType, IContractResolver contractResolver, Boolean append, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at NJsonSchema.JsonReferenceResolver.ResolveReferenceAsync(Object rootObject, String jsonPath, Type targetType, IContractResolver contractResolver, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at NJsonSchema.JsonSchemaReferenceUtilities.JsonReferenceUpdater.VisitJsonReferenceAsync(IJsonReference reference, String path, String typeNameHint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at NJsonSchema.Visitors.AsyncJsonReferenceVisitorBase.VisitAsync(Object obj, String path, String typeNameHint, ISet`1 checkedObjects, Action`1 replacer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at NJsonSchema.Visitors.AsyncJsonReferenceVisitorBase.VisitAsync(Object obj, String path, String typeNameHint, ISet`1 checkedObjects, Action`1 replacer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at NJsonSchema.Visitors.AsyncJsonReferenceVisitorBase.VisitAsync(Object obj, String path, String typeNameHint, ISet`1 checkedObjects, Action`1 replacer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at NJsonSchema.Visitors.AsyncJsonReferenceVisitorBase.VisitAsync(Object obj, String path, String typeNameHint, ISet`1 checkedObjects, Action`1 replacer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at NJsonSchema.Visitors.AsyncJsonReferenceVisitorBase.VisitAsync(Object obj, String path, String typeNameHint, ISet`1 checkedObjects, Action`1 replacer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at NJsonSchema.Visitors.AsyncJsonReferenceVisitorBase.VisitAsync(Object obj, String path, String typeNameHint, ISet`1 checkedObjects, Action`1 replacer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at NJsonSchema.Visitors.AsyncJsonReferenceVisitorBase.VisitAsync(Object obj, String path, String typeNameHint, ISet`1 checkedObjects, Action`1 replacer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at NJsonSchema.Visitors.AsyncJsonReferenceVisitorBase.VisitAsync(Object obj, String path, String typeNameHint, ISet`1 checkedObjects, Action`1 replacer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at NJsonSchema.Visitors.AsyncJsonReferenceVisitorBase.VisitAsync(Object obj, String path, String typeNameHint, ISet`1 checkedObjects, Action`1 replacer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at NJsonSchema.Visitors.AsyncJsonReferenceVisitorBase.VisitAsync(Object obj, String path, String typeNameHint, ISet`1 checkedObjects, Action`1 replacer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at NJsonSchema.Visitors.AsyncJsonReferenceVisitorBase.VisitAsync(Object obj, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at NJsonSchema.JsonSchemaReferenceUtilities.JsonReferenceUpdater.VisitAsync(Object obj, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at NJsonSchema.JsonSchemaReferenceUtilities.UpdateSchemaReferencesAsync(Object rootObject, JsonReferenceResolver referenceResolver, IContractResolver contractResolver, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at NJsonSchema.Infrastructure.JsonSchemaSerialization.FromJsonWithLoaderAsync[T](Func`1 loader, SchemaType schemaType, String documentPath, Func`2 referenceResolverFactory, IContractResolver contractResolver, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>   at NSwag.OpenApiDocument.FromJsonAsync(String data, String documentPath, SchemaType expectedSchemaType, Func`2 referenceResolverFactory, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/NSwag.Core/OpenApiDocument.cs:line 203
1>   at NSwag.Commands.Generation.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreToSwaggerCommand.RunAsync(CommandLineProcessor processor, IConsoleHost host) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/Commands/Generation/AspNetCore/AspNetCoreToOpenApiCommand.cs:line 239
1>   at NSwag.Commands.NSwagDocumentBase.GenerateSwaggerDocumentAsync() in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/NSwagDocumentBase.cs:line 275
1>   at NSwag.Commands.NSwagDocument.ExecuteAsync() in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/NSwagDocument.cs:line 81
1>   at NSwag.Commands.Document.ExecuteDocumentCommand.ExecuteDocumentAsync(IConsoleHost host, String filePath) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/Commands/Document/ExecuteDocumentCommand.cs:line 85
1>   at NSwag.Commands.Document.ExecuteDocumentCommand.RunAsync(CommandLineProcessor processor, IConsoleHost host) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/Commands/Document/ExecuteDocumentCommand.cs:line 32
1>   at NConsole.CommandLineProcessor.ProcessSingleAsync(String[] args, Object input)
1>   at NConsole.CommandLineProcessor.ProcessAsync(String[] args, Object input)
1>   at NSwag.Commands.NSwagCommandProcessor.ProcessAsync(String[] args) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/NSwagCommandProcessor.cs:line 61
```

Whereas if I remove the Schema bit, the build is fine - but obviously the Schema is empty.

```
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "",
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/PaginatedListOfTodoItemBriefDto"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "400": {
        "description": "An error occurs or a business rule fails."
      }
    },
```

I am not sure what I'm missing, maybe it's they way I am trying to generate the Scheme.

Comment: Could not resolve the path `'#/paths//api/...` Is it the strange path, right? Please, check it. It will probably be something like this: `'#/api/...`

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: @ChristianKlemm not yet, I just moved onto other things for now, as I spent quite a bit of time trying to figure it out. I did get something working in the old `Swashbuckle.AspnetCore` version by implementing the` IOperationFilter` - but not success yet with `NSwag.IOperationProcessor`

Comment: @DawoodAwan I was able to do a deep dive into it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, but unlike you because I am having a couple of generic controllers where the response type differs based on generic parameters. The solution is to not generate a schema on the fly and plainly assigning it to the result. Rather, get or generate the schema and set it as a reference.

As an example:

```cs
var dtoType = typeof(FooDto);
var okResponse = new OpenApiResponse
{
    Schema = new JsonSchema()
    {
        Reference = GetSchemaForType(context, dtoType)
    }
};
context.OperationDescription.Operation.Responses.Add(StatusCodes.Status200OK.ToString(), okResponse);
```

while using this method to get or generate the schema:

```cs
private static JsonSchema GetSchemaForType(OperationProcessorContext context, Type type)
{
    var schema = !context.SchemaResolver.HasSchema(type, false)
        ? context.SchemaGenerator.Generate(type, context.SchemaResolver)
        : context.SchemaResolver.GetSchema(type, false);

    return schema;
}
```

If you look at the json you posted above you see that the schema does not include the response schema itself but a reference to it. The OperationDescription is the object that ends up being serialized so you can look at a valid swagger.json to get a reference on how to properly modify it in code.

Btw: same applies to array types. I had issues finding a proper solution for them as well so maybe this helps you out in case you need it.

```cs
var dtoType = typeof(FooDto);

var dtoSchema = GetSchemaForType(context, dtoType);
var okResponse = new OpenApiResponse
{
    Schema = new JsonSchema()
    {
        Type = JsonObjectType.Array,
        Item = new JsonSchema()
        {
            Reference = dtoSchema
        }
    }
};
operation.Responses.Add(StatusCodes.Status200OK.ToString(), okResponse);
```

Comment: Yep this works perfectly, should be included in the official docs I think. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but the accepted solution didn't work for me.

After a lot of debugging I figured out the issue (at least in my case).

Replacing the use of `SchemaGenerator.Generate(...)` with either `GenerateWithReference(...)` or `GenerateWithReferenceAndNullability(...)`.

I ended up with something similar to this:

```csharp
using Namotion.Reflection; // needed for .ToContextualType()

var schema = context.SchemaGenerator.GenerateWithReference<JsonSchema>(
    typeof(ValidationException).ToContextualType(), 
    context.SchemaResolver);
```